# Applying Conditional Logic using XSL

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have an XML document where I get several addresses for a member as address type PRIMARY, MAILING etc. however I only want to read the address as PRIMARY, MAILING when memberId is '0'. Please see the sample xml below.

```
     <core>
     <address>
        <postalZipCode>90017</postalZipCode>
        <updateSource>xxxxxx</updateSource>
        <city>LOS ANGELES</city>
        <stateProvince>CA</stateProvince>
        <type>MAILING</type>
        <line1>818 WEST SEVENTH STREET</line1>
    </address>
    <address>
        <postalZipCode>95014</postalZipCode>
        <updateSource>xxxxxx</updateSource>
        <city>CUPERTINO</city>
        <stateProvince>CA</stateProvince>
        <type>PRIMARY</type>
        <line1>1234 XYZ STREET</line1>
     </address>
      <memberId>0</memberId>
     </core>
```

The XSL condition I am trying to evaluate in my XSLT file is as below -

```
    <xsl:template match="core">
    <xsl:when test="memberId[.='0'] and address/type[.='PRIMARY']">
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="data">
            <fo:block>Line 1</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>            
    </fo:table-row>
```

But this condition check is not working and address is not rendered in the generated document . 
Could the experts here please suggest how do I go about such conditional check ?

Comment: "*I only want to read the address as PRIMARY, MAILING when memberId is '0'.*" That's not a clear statement. Why don't you use an example that also has addresses **other than** PRIMARY or MAILING (and preferably other `member Id`values as well), and show us the expected result of transforming it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't have `<xsl:when>` as a child of anything other than `<xsl:choose>`. I suspect in this case you probably meant to use `<xsl:if>`.

Secondly, your template matches `core`, not the primary `address` element- Not sure if this is intentional or not though.

Thirdly, your template doesn't actually output anything from the source document anyway, unless there's some missing from what you've included here.

As a rule it's generally advisable to write templates with predicates that fit your conditions, rather than explicit conditional logic within a template. I think what you probably want to do is:

```
<xsl:template match="core[memberId='0']/address[type='PRIMARY']">
  <fo:etc..
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: "*it's generally advisable to write templates with predicates that fit your conditions*" I am not sure I agree with such rule. I would say it's generally advisable to **apply templates** selectively. Otherwise the nodes which do not meet your conditions will be processed by the built-in template rules, causing unexpected (and unwanted) results.

Comment: Thank you Flynn. I just had to change from using <xsl:when> to <xsl:if>

Comment: @michael.hor257k I suspect we'll probably have to agree to disagree, to an extent it's a matter of preference and circumstance, but for something simple like this you're probably right; but if there are many different conditions you'll quickly build up large templates that can become difficult to maintain. Personally I'd always include an empty template that matches other conditions, the intent is clearer if the stylesheet explicitly defines no output for other cases.